# colorbox - changing "current"

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using the colorbox-script for lightboxing images. Now I want to change the statement "image x of y" to "x/y", but it doesn't work.

I'm using this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').colorbox({current: "{current}/{total}"});
  });
</script>
```

This is the HTML-output:

```
<a class='colorbox cboxElement'  title="Roll Up Display Start<br /><span style='font-weight:normal; font-size: 9px'>Roll Up Display Start</span>"  href='assets/images/disroll_start.jpg' ><img style="float: right;" title="Roll Up Display Start" src="assets/components/directresize/cache/dr_disroll_start_w200_h437.jpg" alt="Roll Up Display Start"   /></a>
```

I would like to get rid of the part `"<br /><span style='font-weight:normal; font-size: 9px'>Roll Up Display Start</span>"` as well, but I don't know where to change this...

Any tipps from anyone?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').colorbox({current: "{current}/{total}"});
```

That is done correctly.  If it isn't working for you then you've left relevant information out of your post.

The markup in your title attribute doesn't have anything to do with colorbox.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to address the styling of the ColorBox Title string using the plugin's CSS file, not by embedding CSS rules in your markup.

Study the CSS file used by the plugin as the author (JackM) has done an outstanding job on it.
Pay particular attention to the rules on the selector **#cboxTitle**; that should get you more than half-way there.

KJM